# Cuda registers per thread

Tags: cuda, local-storage, profiler

As I understand correctly for the 2.x compute capability devices there's a 63 register limit per thread. Do you know which is the register limit per thread for devices of compute capability 1.3?

I have a big kernel which I'm testing on a GTX260. I'm pretty sure I'm using a lot of registers since the kernel is very complex and I need a lot of local variables. According to the Cuda profiler my register usage is 63 (Static Smem is 68 although I'm not so sure what that means and dynamic Smem is 0), although I'm pretty sure I have more than 63 local variables, so I figured the compiler is reusing registers or spilling them into local memory.

Now I thought the devices of compute capability 1.3 had a higher limit of registers per thread than the 2.x devices. My guess was that the compiler was choosing the 63 limit because I'm using using blocks of 256 threads in which case 256*63 is 16128 while 256*64 is 16384 which is the limit number of registers for a SM of this device. So my guess was that if I lower the number of threads per block I can increase the number of registers in use. So I ran the kernel with blocks of 196 threads. But again the profiler shows 63 registers even though 63*192 is 12096 and 64*192 is 12288 which is way inside the 16384 limit of the SM.

So any idea why the compiler is limiting itself still to 63 registers? Could it be all because of register reuse or is it still spilling registers?

Comment: The answer can to the first part of your question is [here](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#features-technical-specifications.xml)

Comment: Yeah I was looking at that earlier. In the table it says "Number of 32-bit registers per multiprocessor" which is 16K but what I need is the maximum numbers of registers allowed **per thread** which is not specified there. I know that for 2.x devices the limit is 63 but is there a limit for 1.3?

Comment: Keep looking, the per thread number is right underneath

Comment: I think I'm blind, I swear I looked into that list like 10 times. Thank you.

Comment: [Here's](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#features-and-technical-specifications) an updated link.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

max registers per thread is documented [here](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#features-and-technical-specifications__technical-specifications-per-compute-capability)

It is 63 for cc 2.x and 3.0, 128 for cc 1.x and 255 for cc 3.5

The compiler may have decided that 63 registers is enough, and doesn't have use for additional registers.  Registers can be reused, so just because you have a lot of local variables, doesn't necessarily mean that the registers per thread has to be high.

My suggestion would be to use the nvcc `-maxrregcount` [option](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc/index.html#options-for-steering-gpu-code-generation) to specify various limits, and then use the `-Xptxas -v` [option](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc/index.html#options-for-passing-specific-phase-options) to have the compiler tell you how many registers it is using when it creates the PTX.

Comment: You can also use [launch bounds](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#launch-bounds) to have more precise control of registers per thread limit on a per-kernel basis.

Comment: [Here's](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#features-and-technical-specifications) an updated link for max registers per thread and other specs.

Comment: What is the relation between launch bounds and registers per thread or should I say how are they corelated ?

Comment: Launch bounds is a mechanism to limit registers per thread.  The limits are applied in such a way so that your objectives, as indicated by the parameters you pass to the launch bounds API, can be met.