# Cuda PTX registers declaration and using

Tags: c++, cuda, gpgpu, nvidia, ptx

I am trying to reduce number of using registers in my kernel, so I am decide to try inline PTX.

This kernel:

```
#define Feedback(a, b, c, d, e) d^e^(a&c)^(a&e)^(b&c)^(b&e)^(c&d)^(d&e)^(a&d&e)^(a&c&e)^(a&b&d)^(a&b&c)

__global__ void Test(unsigned long a, unsigned long b, unsigned long c, unsigned long d, unsigned long e, unsigned long f, unsigned long j, unsigned long h, unsigned long* res)
{
    res[0] = Feedback( a, b, c, d, e );  
    res[1] = Feedback( b, c, d, e, f );
    res[2] = Feedback( c, d, e, f, j );  
    res[3] = Feedback( d, e, f, j, h );
}
```

Using 14 registers, I am thinking this is more than needs, so I am write Inline PTX:

```
    __global__ void Feedback_ASM(unsigned long a, unsigned long b, unsigned long c, unsigned long d, unsigned long e, unsigned long f, unsigned long j, unsigned long h, unsigned long* res)
{
asm(".reg .u32 %r<10>;\n");

// 1
asm("ld.param.u32   %r1, [__cudaparm__Z7Feedback_ASMmmmmmmmmPm_a];\n"
    "ld.param.u32   %r2, [__cudaparm__Z7Feedback_ASMmmmmmmmmPm_b];\n"
    "ld.param.u32   %r3, [__cudaparm__Z7Feedback_ASMmmmmmmmmPm_c];\n"
    "ld.param.u32   %r4, [__cudaparm__Z7Feedback_ASMmmmmmmmmPm_d];\n"
    "ld.param.u32   %r5, [__cudaparm__Z7Feedback_ASMmmmmmmmmPm_e];\n");

asm("and.b32 %r7, %r1, %r3;\n"
    "xor.b32 %r8, %r7, %r4;\n"
    "xor.b32 %r7, %r8, %r5;\n"
    "and.b32 %r8, %r1, %r5;\n"
    "xor.b32 %r9, %r7, %r8;\n"
    .............................
    "xor.b32 %r8, %r7, %r9;\n"
    "and.b32 %r6, %r1, %r2;\n"
    "and.b32 %r7, %r6, %r3;\n"
    "xor.b32 %r9, %r7, %r8;\n");

asm("ld.param.u32   %r8, [__cudaparm__Z7Feedback_ASMmmmmmmmmPm_res];\n"
    "st.global.u32  [%r8+0], %r9;");     
// 2
...
// 3
...
// 4
...
}
```

But this kernel uses 14 registers too! I am a little confused. I declared only 10 registers, In the ptx file there are no other variables. How I can solve this situation?

Comment: PTX is only an virtual machine, intermediate representation of the code which eventually runs on the hardware (and its SSA, which I think you code actually violates, I'm surprised it compiles). There is no relationship between register allocation in PTX and final register allocation in the assembler emitted machine code.

Comment: It not only compiles, it works correctly. Is there any way to affect the number of registers? In my opinion they really used too much.

Comment: Are you passing the desired compute capability during compilation? Also why is it really that important for you to reduce the amount of registers used? 14 doesn't seem like too many.

Comment: Because in this case I calculate only 4 variables but in complete programm I need 32 variables, so number of registers increases to 60. As a result I have 17% occupancy. I trying to find the way to controll this process.
P.S. Sorry, but I dont understand your first question :(

Comment: Which CUDA version are you using and how are you compiling? You can influence `nvcc` using `-maxrregcount`, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/17554199/678093

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As indicated already, PTX is an intermediate code.  PTX "registers" are virtual registers and don't necessarily reflect actual device register usage.

To get an idea of actual device register usage, compile using the ptxas verbose option:

```
nvcc -Xptxas -v ...
```

or use one of the profilers.  You can also inspect the machine code directly using:

```
cuobjdump -sass myexe
```

(where `myexe` is replaced with the name of your executable).

To control register usage, you can use the nvcc compile option:

```
nvcc -maxrregcount 10 ...
```

(where 10 is replaced with how many registers per thread you want all kernels in your code to be limited to) or you can use the [launch bounds](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#launch-bounds) directive in your code, which can control register usage on a kernel-by-kernel basis.