# CUDA "too many resources requested for launch" in Release, not in Debug

Tags: cuda

I am using Visual Studio 2012 and when I launch my program in Debug mode, it runs smoothly.
However, when I run it in release mode, I get the error "too many resources requested for launch" on one of my kernel.

I went to compare the compilation parameters between debug and release, and it seems that when I change the option "Generate GPU Debug Information" to "Yes (-G)", the problem disappears.

Why is it so ? Is there something I am missing to be able to run the program without that option ?

Compile options:

```
D:\Dev\CUDA\bin\nvcc.exe -gencode=arch=compute_50,code=\"sm_50,compute_50\" --use-local-env --cl-version 2012 -ccbin "D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\bin\x86_amd64"  -ID:\Dev\CUDA\include -ID:\Dev\CUDA\include  -G -lineinfo  --keep-dir x64\Release -maxrregcount=0  --machine 64 --compile -cudart static     -DWIN32 -DWIN64 -DNDEBUG -D_CONSOLE -D_MBCS -Xcompiler "/EHsc /W3 /nologo /O2 /Zi  /MD  " -o x64\Release\main.cu.obj "D:\Dev\Projets\CUDA\ProjAdvMetrixCuda6\Discrete choice v2\main.cu"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why is it so ?

It's likely due to a registers per thread issue.  Code generation is significantly different between release and debug versions, and this affects the registers used per GPU thread.  If you use too many, a kernel will not launch.

You can quickly confirm this by modifying this particular command line switch:

```
-maxrregcount=0
```

to some other value.  This is possible to do in one of the Visual Studio project configuration fields.   I would start with a value of something like 20 for this.  If that causes the release project to run, then you have a registers per thread issue.  You can get more info about that by studying some of the answers discussing it already, such as the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29297960/cuda-ptx-registers-declaration-and-using/29382675?s=1|0.0000#29382675)

Note that this problem is not necessarily just pertinent to release vs. debug.  *Anything* that affects code generation could lead to a similar problem, such as 32bit/64bit, or other project or compiler setting differences.  The solution path is the same.

Comment: Thanks a lot Robert. You targeted the issue correctly, modifying the maxregcount value worked. Now I know what to look for in the documentation :)